# FTP server connecting issue (FTP delivering issue)

Tags: java, ftp

When I tried to deliver one file through FTP server it is not delivering, I am getting error connecting to FTP server error:

> Node name:Transport Content, Cause: Exception: Error during transport
>   step. Error: Exception: Error disconnecting from the ftp server:
>   NullPointerException:

when i normally write one java class to check FTP server it is delivering but via tomcat server it is not delivering.

Comment: I'm afraid nobody is going to be able to help you unless you show us the code that is producing those error messages.  (Apart from lucky guesses)

Comment: Is there a stack trace following that line?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is problem with connectivity. Check the configuration values used (server / port/ userid / pwd)

Comment: Yes, I have checked (server/username/password/port). That is not a problem is there is any other suggestion.

Comment: will u please share the code which gives this error. so i will able to understand where it goes wrong...\

Comment: please read these too...   http://support.2brightsparks.com/knowledgebase/articles/213469-common-ftp-errors-and-socket-error-messages

Comment: I am having commons-net-3.3.jar in my project while building the project this jar was not building so only it shows ftpclient class not found exception  and null pointer exception.
I added this below line in my build.xml then FTP delivery is happening successfully.

<copy file="${lib}/commons-net-3.3.jar" todir="${build}" />

why I am facing this type of issue in another machine same project running without adding this line in build.xml.
How it differing one system to another system.